# How to split a column in Excel using a delimiter and creating multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have this column in my table:

[image]

I want to split it by the "|" delimiter. So I want to end up with this:

[image]

I'm unsure as to how I will accomplish this.

Comment: use Text to Columns, its under the Data Tab.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you so much! I thought that Text to Columns was meant for something entirely different, but it turns out it's exactly what I needed!